# Append current query string to private file urls?

Tags: 8, files

If I use [template_preprocess_file_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/template_preprocess_file_link/8.9.x), can I add the current url query string and append it to the link per user? Will this link be cached for all users?

Update:

This appends it, but does seem to get cached:

```
  if (preg_match('/private:\/\//i', $file_entity->getFileUri())) {
    $query = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->query->all();

    if (!empty($query)) {
      $options['query'] = $query;
    }
  }

  $variables['link'] = \Drupal::l($link_text, Url::fromUri($url, $options));
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this cache context seemed to do it (although I do not know if this is bulletproof):

```
  if (preg_match('/private:\/\//i', $file_entity->getFileUri())) {
    $query = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->query->all();

    if (!empty($query)) {
      $options['query'] = $query;
    }

    $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.query_args';
  }
```